# How to define a single copy constructor for template classes?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, constructor

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Matrix
{

public:

    Matrix() = default;

    template <typename U>
    Matrix(const Matrix<U>& matrix) {
        std::cout << "Copying internal data..." << std::endl;
    }

//    Matrix(const Matrix<T>& matrix) {
//        std::cout << "Copying internal data..." << std::endl;
//    }

    Matrix(Matrix<T>&& matrix) {
        std::cout << "Moving internal data..." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Matrix<int> m1{};
    Matrix<double> m2 = m1;
    Matrix<int> m3 = m1;
}
```

Here, I have a matrix class, it can be a matrix of `int`, a `double`, or any numerical value.

I want to define a copy constructor that accepts a matrix with any numerical type and copies its elements.

For example, suppose `m1` is a `Matrix<double>` = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, ...}, `Matrix<int> m2 = m1` should set `m2` to be {1, 2, 3, ...}.

Also, I want to have a move constructor, but it doesn't make any sense to have a move constructor for any type except for its own type (in this example, it's `T`).

This is because I'm going to steal the pointer pointing to the array of numbers, and to do so, it has to be of the same type.

Defining a move constructor that accepts only `Matrix<T>` automatically deletes the copy constructor for `Matrix<T>`.

I realized that since the parameter in the copy constructor I tried to make isn't necessarily of the same type, it's not considered to be a copy constructor, and unless I write a copy constructor specifically for `Matrix<T>` (the commented copy constructor), the code won't compile.

But even if I don't have a copy constructor, I have a constructor that accepts a matrix of any type. Why is it looking specifically for the copy constructor?

How do I define my copy constructor only once, and have it deal with matrices of any type?

Comment: "*How do I define my copy constructor only once, and have it deal with matrices of any type?*" I'm afraid not, from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor): A copy constructor of class `T` is a **non-template** constructor whose first parameter is `T&‍`, `const T&‍`, `volatile T&‍`, or `const volatile T&‍`, and either there are no other parameters, or the rest of the parameters all have default values.

Comment: `Matrix<double> m2 = m1;` -- This is not a copy constructor, as the types are not the same.  You have to write a "normal" constructor that takes an A and creates a B from it.

Comment: [converting example](https://godbolt.org/z/dGx65aPhh) (for ctors only - add converting assignment operators too if needed).

Comment: I agree that it's not a copy constructor anymore, but it's a valid constructor that takes a matrix of any type. Why do I get a compilation error if I don't have the copy constructor? Why doesn't it call this template constructor, which takes a matrix of any type?

Comment: @StackExchange123 Because the copy constructor is implicitly deleted.

Comment: The copy constructor is deleted, but there is another constructor that fits, why isn't it getting called?

Comment: Also, if I have to have a copy constructor, is it possible to call the template constructor from it, to avoid writing the same code again?

Comment: fwiw, you do not need to add "Update" (or "Edit") to your quesiton. If someone wants to see the edithistory they can do so here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70367073/revisions. A [mcve] is the important part of the question, placing it after some "not the real code" and lots of text makes the question hard to read

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sure. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what is your problem. Your code seem to work fine: https://godbolt.org/z/a63ncdbf9

Comment: @MarekR Comment out the copy constructor like the OP: https://godbolt.org/z/8qdrr78s6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But even if I don't have a copy constructor, I have a constructor that accepts a matrix of any type. Why is it looking specifically for the copy constructor?

In overload resolution it is not *find the best usable function*. Instead, it is *find the best function and try to use it*. If it can't because of access restrictions or being deleted, then you get a compiler error.

In your case, you have the template constructor that stamps out `Matrix(const Matrix<double>& matrix)` (`#1`), and it also finds `Matrix(const Matrix<double>& matrix) = delete` (`#2`) which was implicitly generated by the compiler because you have a user provided move constructor.  In overload resolution, if two functions have the exact same signature, and one of those is a specialization of a template, the non template version is chosen.  In this case that is `#2` which is deleted, so you get an error for accessing a deleted function.

So to answer

> How do I define my copy constructor only once, and have it deal with matrices of any type?

You can't.  If you want `Foo<T>` to be copyable from another `Foo<T>` then you need to provide a copy constructor.  If you want `Foo<T>` to be copyable from a `Foo<U>`, then you need to add a converting constructor for that.  Ideally you would use something like a `std::vector` as the underlying storage for the matrix elements, and if you do, then you can just follow the rule of zero and your class becomes

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{

public:

    Matrix() = default;

    template <typename U>
    Matrix(const Matrix<U>& other) data(other.data.begin(), other.data.end()) {}

private:
    std::vector<T> data;
};
```